# Android: TableLayout next to LinearLayout

Tags: android, layout, android-linearlayout, tablelayout

In Android I'm trying to use this xml to get a TableLayout next to a LinearLayout. But I can't get it working. The TableLayout always takes up the full width of the screen. How can I get it to share the screen width with the LinearLayout?

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:weightSum="1" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TableLayout android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="0.5">
        <TableRow>
            <TextView android:text="Name1:" />
            <TextView android:text="Value1" />
        </TableRow>     
        <TableRow>
            <TextView android:text="Name2:" />
            <TextView android:text="Value2" />
        </TableRow>             
    </TableLayout>
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="0.5"></LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: the xml is working fine its producing the desired result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like stated above, don't put the table width as 0dp.  I would make the root element a Relative layout then state that the linear layout should be to the right of the table layout.

Comment: Worked perfect with a Relative Layout. I think the problem might been in the Emulator as my first xml also worked when I tested on real device.

Answer (score 0):

this says that your layout width of the linear layout is 0dp. make it wrap content and have the table layout with weight: 1 > linear: 0 and table layout set to fill parent.